# new Event('myEvent') does not compile in typescript

Tags: typescript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

I am trying to create a custom event in typescript like above example:

```
var ev: Event = new Event('myEvent');
```

Sadly, in lib.d.ts, **new** for Event is parameterless:

```
declare var Event: {
    prototype: Event;
    new(): Event; // NO PARAMETERS!
    CAPTURING_PHASE: number;
    AT_TARGET: number;
    BUBBLING_PHASE: number;
}
```

Thus the constructor with a string parameter (event name) does not compile.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most possibly you might be having an older version of typescript installed with its specific library files. The definition of [`Event` is this way](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/webworker.generated.d.ts#L187).

```
declare var Event: {
    prototype: Event;
    new(type: string, eventInitDict?: EventInit): Event;
    AT_TARGET: number;
    BUBBLING_PHASE: number;
    CAPTURING_PHASE: number;
}
```

I am not quite sure, but i believe typescript variables are not partials unlike interfaces. You could upgrade TS version, update lib.d.ts manually to edit the type or create a new type and use it.

Comment: in case you cannot upgrade: 
var Evt: any = Event;
...
var e: Event = new Evt('myEvent');